# JControllerLegacy not found, joomla 2.5, yoothemes zoo

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have installed `yoothemes zoo 3.11`.The installed message indicated that everything went in correctly but when I go to the component i get this following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'JControllerLegacy' not found in
>   /home/p446072r/public_html/administrator/components/com_zoo/framework/classes/controller.php
>   on line 17

Answer (score 5):

The JControllerLegacy class was added in Joomla 2.5.6. Upgrade to that, and you'll be fine. If you're not able to upgrade, you could also define the classes yourself, since they are just a shell that extends JController. However, the recommended way would be to upgrade to at least 2.5.6.

Comment: Would you mind marking this as the accepted answer, so others will know it worked for you without searching the comments? It gives a green checkmark under the upvotes, and makes this answer sticky.